Transfer docker container logs to GCP using Ops-Agent
I want to transfer my container logs to GCP logging UI using the gcloud-ops-agent.
I tried to use the gcplogs-docker-driver to transfer the logs it is working but it is showing all container logs under the driver oprion.
I want to explicit the logs using container-name.
